# $U$ takes the same value on $\pi$ then $U$ is saturated

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

Let $\pi : X \to Y$ be any map, and $U$ be a subset of $X$.

*The problem is:*

"$\forall x\in U$, $ \pi (x) = \pi(x') $, then $x' \in U$"  then  $U$ is saturated.

(U is saturated $\iff$ $\exists V \subset Y $ s.t. $U = \pi ^{-1}(V)$ )

*My understanding is:*

To show $U$ is saturated, it is enough to show $U = \pi ^{-1}(\pi(U))$.

$U \subset \pi ^{-1}(\pi(U))$ is satisfied for any map $\pi$.

We will show $U \supset \pi ^{-1}(\pi(U))$.

Suppose $ x\in \pi ^{-1}(\pi(U))$.

$\iff \pi(x) \in \pi(U)$

By definition of $\pi(U)$, there is some $a \in U$ s.t. $\pi(x) = \pi(a)$,

so hypothesis says $x\in U$.

My proof is fine? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: My pleasure. $\,$